# How can we train and test a neural network with UNB ISCX benchmark dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, denial-of-service, intrusion-detection

I have tried with KDD dataset on my neural net and now I want to extend using ISCX dataset. Some part of this dataset contains the HTTP DOS attacks labelled represents replica of real time network traffic but I couldn't figure out how can I convert them into Neural inputs(numeric) to train and test my neural net which would classify these intrusion vectors..
Appreciated for Any pointers..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with this data set, but if you have sufficient information about features and values of each feature, you can create .arff file quickly and then use WEKA very easy.
Although you can use many applications but some user-friendly applications such as GUI of WEKA has the capability of working with discrete and non numerical features very easy. and can help you to start working with your data set as fast as possible.